# Accuracy of the center with hough circle transform

Tags: opencv, geometry, hough-transform

I try to get the center of circles using Hough Circle algorithm from
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/houghcircles.cpp
but I need more accurate coordinates.

When I get those coordinates like
this

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
{
     Vec3i c = circles[i];
     cout<<c[0]<<"  "<<c[1]<<endl;
}
```

it prints just the integer part.
Is there any posibility to get the center more precise(4 decimals or more)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get accurate center points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958751/how-can-i-get-accurate-center-points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly converting the coordinates to integers by assigning them to an integer vector (`Vec3i`). If you print them like this, you will print the values as you get them from OpenCV:

```
cout<<circles[0]<<"  "<<circles[1]<<endl;
```

However, these results might not be as accurate as you desire. In that case, you are out of luck with your current approach as OpenCV does not provide more accurate results.

Comment: Yes you are right but even if i do like that all the values looks like ---.5 , it is always .5 it is not accurate!Do you know any possibility to find them more accurate?

Comment: See my edited answer: You likely won't get more accurate results with that method. The only thing you could try is setting the `dp` parameter to a value like `1./16` to get a hough accumulator that is 16 times the image resolution. However, I don't know if that would actually work...